# How to print the contents of a text file to the Jenkins script console?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins instance is on Wondows. My file is on `%JENKINS_HOME%/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js`

In Jenkins Script console I try this but do not work (groovy error).

```
println %JENKINS_HOME%/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js
println "%JENKINS_HOME%/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js"
println ("%JENKINS_HOME%/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js")
echo %JENKINS_HOME%/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js
```

**Console error:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'tools' @ line 1, column 30.
  println %JENKINS_HOME%/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js
```

**EDIT**

I try `println $JENKINS_HOME/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js` but I have this result error:

**Console error:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '-' @ line 1, column 34.
   println $JENKINS_HOME/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$` in starting of variable name instead of `%` . Grroovy understands java syntax only. Refer section 4.4.1 String interpolation of below link.
https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html

Comment: I try your proposale but do not work. So I edit my post with this.

Comment: `println "$JENKINS_HOME/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js"` this will work. But it will just print path of file. For printing content you need to use file class of jenkins

Answer (score 0):

```
new File("$JENKINS_HOME/tools/tools-package-json-get-property/version.js").eachLine { line ->
    println line
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows , then you can just use `type <filename>` command to print the contents of a text file.

 In Jenkins file just add below and you will see the contents in the console output:

```
bat "type $JENKINS_HOME\\tools\\tools-package-json-get-property\\version.js"
```

Note: For Windows I have used `\\` instead of `/` 
If you are running on linux, then you can just use `cat <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

Well in groovy console it works like

```
FileToRead = new File('C:\\somepath\\somefile.txt')
print FileToRead.text
```

Inside of my Jenkins BlueOcean pipelines it works, but you could run it into an error kind of "need script approval", which can be done into "http://jenkins:8080/manage/scriptApproval/" after pipeline fails. Then just restart pipeline.